# htaccess wordpress redirect doesn't work properly

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Wordpress is installed in sub-directory and I want to add redirect rule for whoever comes to http://example.com/folder/ to be redirected to  http://example.com/custom-page/ and I was able to do this with:

```
Redirect /folder/ http://example.com/custom-page/
```

The problem is that I cannot access wp admin page because of this redirect.
How can I exclude wp-admin from the rule above?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RedirectMatch

```
 RedirectMatch ^/folder/((?!wp-admin).*)$ http://example.com/custom-page/$1
```

The pattern **((?!wp-admin)folder/.*)** matches any request excluding **/wp-admin** and redirects it  to the destination url

Comment: folder is missing on the right side so I've put it there:  RedirectMatch ^/((?!wp-admin)folder/.*) http://example.com/folder/custom-page/$1 It doesn't work: here is what I get when I add this: http://example.com/folder/custom-page/folder/custom-page/folder/custom-page/folder/custom-page/folder/custom-page/folder/custom-page/folder/custom-page/folder/custom-page/folder/custom-page/folder/custom-page/folder/custom-page/folder/custom-page/folder it is like some infinite loop

Comment: RedirectMatch ^/folder/((?!wp-admin).*)$ http://example.com/folder/custom-page/$1 it doesn't work... Again the output is the same as the first one... This should be added to root dir, right? Since I have 2 installations. one is representing http://example.com and the other install is in /folder/ which is located in the root of the first installation... Am I doing something wrong regarding that?

Comment: Where is your wp-admin file located?

Comment: the that I want to use here is in http://example.com/folder/wp-admin/  I can't access to this wp admin folder, however I have another wp-admin in http://example.com/wp-admin/ and I am trying in htaccess which is located in the root (http://example.com)